# Powershell - If FILE (wildcard) exists & is greater than 0kb

Tags: powershell

I can successfully check if a file exists and is greater than 0kb using the following:

```
$getFILE = 'C:\DIR\FILE1.txt'

IF (test-path $getFILE){
    IF ((get-item $getFILE).length -gt 0) {
        "OK";return 0
    }
    ELSE {
        "0 bytes";return 2
    }
}
ELSE {
    "doesn't exist";return 1
}
```

I can check if a wildcard file exists using the following:

```
$getFILE = 'C:\DIR\FILE*.*'

IF (test-path $getFILE){
    "OK";return 0
}
else {
    "doesn't exist";return 1
}
```

I cannot get the two concepts to work together though. In the following, if the wildcard file exists; the return is always 0:

```
$getFILE = 'C:\DIR\FILE*.*'

IF (test-path $getFILE){
    IF ((get-item $getFILE).length -gt 0) {
        "OK";return 0
    }
    else {
        "0 bytes";return 2
    }
}
else {
    "doesn't exist";return 1
}
```

Comment: Your code will never work because your second example is flawed. You write `$getFILE = 'C:\DIR\FILE*.*'` yet you test against foo.txt.

Comment: Oops, sorry. That was a typo. Corrected code does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a bit more playing around and I've come up with something that is working:

```
$vDIR = 'C:\DIR'
$vFILE = 'FILE*.*'

$proc = @(Get-ChildItem $vDIR -Recurse -Include $vFile | Where {$_.length -gt 0})
If ($proc.count -gt 0) {
   ForEach ($item in $proc) {
      Do a bunch of stuff
   }
Else {
   Do this other thing
}
```

If anyone has a cleaner solution, I would still love to see it.

EDIT: Changed my solution quite a bit. Again, if there is a better way to do this; I'm super open to suggestions that will help me improve my overall knowledge/skills.

Comment: This seems ambiguous to me. There seems to be an assumption that  a wildcard pattern will only return a single file. Is you goal to only determine if at least one file in a group matches your criteria?

Comment: Exactly. This is for a workflow that will perform a collection of functions ForEach file in a directory that meets specific criteria (name convention and not 0kb). If the requirements are not meet for group 1, the workflow moves to group 2, etc.

Comment: Much clearer what's going on! You don't really need the `If` condition for the `ForEach`, it will already only execute if `$proc.count > 0`. so: `ForEach ($item in $proc) {
   Do a bunch of stuff
}
If ($proc.count -eq 0) {
   Do this other thing
}`